# When mounting Rails Engine, module's name is not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-engines

I have a Rails Engine github_webhooks with Module GithubWebhooks.

In the Engine, I have:

```rb
module GithubWebhooks
  class EventController < ApplicationController
    require 'octokit'
    client = Octokit::Client.new(GithubWebhooks.access_token)

    def destroy
       ...code here...
    end

  end
end

# pullrequest_controller.rb
```

and in lib/github_webhooks.rb,

```rb
require "github_webhooks/engine"

module GithubWebhooks
  mattr_accessor :access_token 
  mattr_accessor :base_url
end

# github_webhooks.rb
```

There's supposed to be an initializer file under `/config` in the Rails app, that allows the user to put in their OAuth access token (`:access_token`) and a base URL to `POST` to (`:base_url`).

When I try to mount the Rails Engine to my app (`sample_app`), I do the following, which I understand to be standard procedure:

I place this line in my gemfile:

```rb
gem 'github_webhooks', git: 'https://github.com/path_to/my_repo'

# Gemfile
```

and then in the routes, I write:

```rb
mount GithubWebhooks::Engine, at: "/github_webhooks"

# routes.rb
```

I already figured out how to use environment variables by placing the token in a `.yml` file and then use gitignore to safely allow users to commit their changes to their own app, without including their token in the commit. I was able to verify that by using ENV[], I could get the token as needed. So that's not the actual problem. **Which brings me to the real problem.**

Rails doesn't seem to recognize the name of my engine, because the line in the routes file seems to be causing the issue. It gives the error

> /home/mschneider25/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant GithubWebhooks (NameError)

I'm not really sure why it says GithubWebhooks is uninitialized; that's the name of the module in the Engine. **What am I missing, that would make Rails recognize my engine and the modules that are inside it?**

Comment: Did you do `bundle install` and then restart the `rails s`?

Comment: Also, did you `require` the engine in your `sample_app`?

Comment: @jvillian what syntax do I use to require the engine, and in what file?

Answer (score 0):

Try requiring the gem by putting:

```
require 'github_webhooks'
```

in `config/application.rb`. Or,

```
gem 'github_webhooks', git: 'https://github.com/path_to/my_repo', require: 'github_webhooks'
```

in your `Gemfile`.